# Connecting to excel sheet using jdbc without specifying DSN to Excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, jdbc

I want to connect to an excel sheet using jdbc or some other method but i do not want to specify DSN for the same using administrative tool. Is their someway to do it using code? If yes how ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are many solutions to access excel from Java. Apache POI is something I use

Comment: The File i am using is more than 15 MB. Using POI gives me out of memory error. Because POI trys to load than entire sheet into JVM at once

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is also possible to connect to a spreadsheet without using DSN, which provides a more flexible way within code to point JDBC at an Excel file of interest without the accesses to a client registry to define the required DSN. Without DSN, the db connection is created as following, please not the difference of constructed JDBC URL:

```
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver
(*.xls)};DBQ=C:/Documents and Settings/myPath/Desktop/qa.xls");
```

Here DBQ defines the path to the target spreadsheet file (qa.xls). Both backslash and forward slash work well.

Source: [Available source](http://xytang.blogspot.in/2008/02/how-to-connect-to-excel-spreadsheet.html)

Comment: I get the following error

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

I have added the ojdbc jar

Comment: Provide default driver also

Comment: What do you mean by default driver  ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are eluding to is a DSN less connection string. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165866
for details. 
Yet, I would opt for Apache POI as mentioned by Jayan 14.

Comment: The File i am using is more than 15 MB. Using POI gives me out of memory error. Because POI trys to load than entire sheet into JVM at once

Comment: 15MB is peanuts. Change the VM settings to allow for more heap and/or stack space.

Comment: The system i am developing is to be used by different users on different machine. I dont find it as correct approach

Answer (score 0):

try changing the driver name from `Microsoft Excel Driver(*.xls)` to Driver do `Microsoft Excel(*.xls)`

`java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Driver do Microsoft Excel(*.xls)};DBQ=C:/Documents and Settings/myPath/Desktop/qa.xls");`

and if you want to update the excel file use the following connection string:

`java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Driver do Microsoft Excel(*.xls)};DBQ=C:/Documents and Settings/myPath/Desktop/qa.xls;ReadOnly=0");`