# Trying to connect to MS Excel 2007 [wtihout creating DSN] - Error: Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: java, database, excel

I am trying to connect to MS Excel and read it as a DB using below code -

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ="+"C:\\excel.xls"+";READONLY=false");
        statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery( query );
        return rs;
```

But getting following error -

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.testcaseautomation.driver.Excel.ExecQry(Excel.java:18)
    at com.ibm.testcaseautomation.driver.JUnitDriver.main(JUnitDriver.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I am using Windows 7 64 bit.
Tried with JDK 1.7 (both 32 and 64 bit, by changing from Winodws ->Preferences) but no luck.

MS Office version is 2007.

Comment: Have you added your data source in the *ODBC Data Source Administrator*?

Comment: I am sure thats not always needed. I am trying without DSN as also asked here  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181119/connecting-to-excel-sheet-using-jdbc-without-specifying-dsn-to-excel-sheet).

Comment: The ojdbc jar is added to the classpath?! Also, why are you not using Apache POI instead?

Comment: I would prefer Apache POI but its not just me and my code. Classpath seems okay to me.

Comment: try with path separator written like this "/" not this "\\". see accepted answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181119/connecting-to-excel-sheet-using-jdbc-without-specifying-dsn-to-excel-sheet?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Finally, got it work.

1. One need JDK 32 bit. Point eclipse to jdk 32 bit from Windows->Preferences
2. Even after step 1, the system library still points to 64 bit. So remove that and change to 32 bit manually under Java Build Path->Libraries. With above lines, it would work.

[image]

Comment: Man, you're so generous!