# How to read excel sheet stored on application server

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

How can I read an Excel file stored on an application server?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181119/connecting-to-excel-sheet-using-jdbc-without-specifying-dsn-to-excel-sheet) and most of the solutions which I have gone through show to read it from a physical location of the local computer.

I would like to read it from an application server. Can someone suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) for read the file. e.g.:

```
InputStream inputStream = new URL("http://localhost/report.xls").openStream();

//Get the workbook instance for XLS stream
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
```

See also [*Read / Write Excel File In Java Using Apache POI*](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/).

Answer (score 0):

You really have two different problems: reading the excel spreadsheet and reading a file from a server. I doubt you're going to find a tool for both. I would download the file to a temporary file and then read that using your Excel reader. Divide and conquer.

Comment: Isn't it possible to read the file directly from application server and not downloading as a temporary file? Probably something in-memory?

Comment: Would make sense. Would make sense that someone wrote a library to read a remote resource as a file. Problem is the way his JDBC solution works. Anyway, don't know how to do any of that.