# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified for Java8 using oracle driver

Tags: java, excel, oracle, jdbc, java-8

i want to run sql queries on Microsoft excel, so that i can fetch any row or any column based on the sql query. Below is the code which i have written

```
Connection con = null;
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver(*.xls)};DBQ="+path+"; ReadOnly=0");`
```

// Here path is the path to the excel file in my local.

When i run this i am getting invalid oracle URL specified error. I have a doubt on the URL format that i need to specify for querying excel sheets. Is there any other way to read excel sheet using sql queries without using DSN.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:287)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:550)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use an Oracle driver to access Excel?

Comment: What is the `path` you're supplying?

Comment: path is the location of the xls file. Ex: C:\\test.xls

Comment: As per my knowledge JDBC driver is not supported by Java8. Hence i am using oracle driver. By using this simply i can query the excel and get the specific cell value.

Comment: The Oracle driver can only connect to the Oracle database. Why do you even think this would work?

Answer (score 2):

See [Connecting to excel sheet using jdbc without specifying DSN to Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181119/connecting-to-excel-sheet-using-jdbc-without-specifying-dsn-to-excel-sheet)

You certainly don't want to use the Oracle driver for this.